# I'm trying to setup django on my system and had a problem with DB migration using XAMP

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, tensorflow

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'djangomypro',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '123456',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': ''
    }
}
```

This is my configuration.

After running `python manage.py migrate` in terminal, I get the following result.

> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 15, in
>   
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/home/vishal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 381, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "/home/vishal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 375, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/home/vishal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 316, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "/home/vishal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 350, in execute
>       self.check()   File "/home/vishal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 379, in check
>       include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,   File "/home/vishal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py",
>   line 59, in _run_checks
>       issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])   File "/home/vishal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py",
>   line 71, in run_checks
>       new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)   File "/home/vishal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/database.py",
>   line 10, in check_database_backends
>       issues.extend(conn.validation.check(**kwargs))   File "/home/vishal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py",
>   line 9, in check
>       issues.extend(self._check_sql_mode(**kwargs))   File "/home/vishal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py",
>   line 13, in _check_sql_mode
>       with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:   File "/home/vishal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
>   line 255, in cursor
>       return self._cursor()   File "/home/vishal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
>   line 232, in _cursor
>       self.ensure_connection()   File "/home/vishal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
>   line 216, in ensure_connection
>       self.connect()   File "/home/vishal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",
>   line 89, in **exit**
>       raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value   File "/home/vishal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
>   line 216, in ensure_connection
>       self.connect()   File "/home/vishal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
>   line 194, in connect
>       self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)   File "/home/vishal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py",
>   line 227, in get_new_connection
>       return Database.connect(**conn_params)   File "/home/vishal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/**init**.py",
>   line 94, in Connect
>       return Connection(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/vishal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
>   line 327, in **init**
>       self.connect()   File "/home/vishal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
>   line 598, in connect
>       self._request_authentication()   File "/home/vishal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
>   line 862, in _request_authentication
>       auth_packet = self._process_auth(plugin_name, auth_packet)   File "/home/vishal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
>   line 933, in _process_auth
>       pkt = self._read_packet()   File "/home/vishal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
>   line 683, in _read_packet
>       packet.check_error()   File "/home/vishal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py",
>   line 220, in check_error
>       err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)   File "/home/vishal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/err.py",
>   line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
>       raise errorclass(errno, errval) django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password:
>   YES)")

Answer (score 0):

looks like django is not able to connect to your database. can you verify if your able to connect using a database client. you can use MYSQLWorkbench to verify this. try logging in with the same parameters you've set for django. I'm not sure but you should be able to see mysql running in your task manager.

you can also try this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'djangomypro',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '123456',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}
```

django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

Comment: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")`